# Visio: Create tables

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007

What's the easiest way to create tables in visio or at least be able to copy them as tables from Excel?

Comment: In Visio 2013, the same method works. Go to the "Insert" tab and select "Object" and from that menu you can select "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" or if you are looking for a table like we see in Word, select "Microsoft Word Document," and all the familiar Word banner will appear at the top where you can "Insert" > "Table"

Comment: The information above from MajorMinor refers to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Visio 2010 go to Insert -> Object -> Microsoft Excel Worksheet. You can also create tables from the shapes in Visio in the following way.

1. Open the stencil containing the table shape you want: click the Shapes button on the Standard toolbar, select Charts And Graphs and then select Charting Shapes.
   Visio adds the stencil to your drawing.
2. Drag the Grid shape from the stencil to the location on the page you want.
   The Custom Properties dialog box appears.
3. Click the arrows to enter the number of rows and columns you want.
   You can always add rows and columns to your table later.
4. Click OK.
5. If you want to change the cell width, you can grab a grid handle and expand or shrink the grid.
   Visio adds a table with your specifications to the drawing page.
6. If you want to use angled column labels, drag the Column Header shape from the Charting Shapes stencil into position over the first table column. Repeat this task for each column and resize as necessary to fit the column.
7. If you want to have separate row labels, drag the Row Header shape from the Charting Shapes stencil into position to the left of the first row. Repeat for each row and resize as necessary to fit the row.
8. To add text, click a row header, column header, or table cell, and then type

Answer (score 3):

You can select "Insert" and then select Object -> Excel Worksheet (new or from file).